# AutoHotkey send {Del} not work in explorer on Win10

Tags: autohotkey

I want to use **Alt+d** to trigger **Delete**.

```
!d::Send, {delete}
```

This works almost everywhere except in explorer. Nothing happens when select a file and press **Alt+d**. Why is that?

Environment: latest AutoHotKey,  Windows 10-64bit

Comment: Alt+D is used to focus on the address bar.  Not sure if you can override that... Does your AHK actually prevent the address bar from being selected?

Comment: The address bar isn't selected if I press Alt+D, the focus is still on the selected file.

Comment: I can confirm that it doesn't work with file explorer in Win10. Interestingly, it does seem to trigger a ctrl press (at least with right alt key). I don't know why to either of those. I also tried many variations with no success. Sorry, I do not have a solution for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
!d::
    IfWinActive ahk_class CabinetWClass ; explorer
    {
        ; The control retrieved by this command is the one that has keyboard focus
        ControlGetFocus, FocusedControl, A  ; A means the active window
        ; MsgBox %FocusedControl%
        If FocusedControl contains DirectUIHWND,SysListView
             SendInput, {AppsKey}d
        else
            Send, {delete}
    }
    else
        Send, {delete}
return
```

https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/ControlGetFocus.htm

Comment: Why? Please add some explanation to your code such that others can learn from it

Comment: It's not about me specially not understanding something. But as you are a long-time user on SO, you should know that good answers contain explanations such that others can learn from it. If these commands are so simple, there must be a reason the OP asked here about it instead of just writing that down

Comment: @user3419297 The `AppsKey` won't work when delete any text in explorer, such as edit when rename file, in address bar,  or in search filter.  Is it possible to send raw Delete key, that should work for all these.

Comment: @aj3423, maybe we can find an answer to this question, if you explain why you prefer the Alt+d combination instead of pressing the Delete key for deleting a file or text in explorer (It will narrow down the possible solutions).

Comment: Hmm. Perhaps holding "`alt`" and "`appskey`" together doesn't work when pressed at the same time (just try pushing them at the same time in explorer). So, maybe try putting in a "`keywait`" statement in to wait until alt is released before sending appskey?

Comment: @user3419297 The 'Delete' key is too far away, programmers don't like move their hands away from the main keyboard area when working, there're tools like  'vim'/'emacs' for editor, 'vimium' for browser, and now AHK for explorer :)

Comment: @user3419297 The 'SysListView' doesn't work, but 'DirectUIHWND3' works. `MsgBox %FocusedControl%`  shows 'DirectUIHWND3'

Comment: OK, I edited the answer to include DirectUIHWND and SysListView (SysListView works for me and maybe for other users too) It can be changed in another OS edition.

Answer (score 0):

For AHK V2 and Win 11:

```
!d::
{
    if WinActive("ahk_class CabinetWClass") ; explorer
    {
        FocusedControl := ControlGetClassNN(ControlGetFocus("A"))
        if (FocusedControl ~= "i)(DirectUIHWND|DirectUIHWND2|SysListView)")
             SendInput("{AppsKey}d")
        else
            Send("{delete}")
    }
    else
        Send("{delete}")
return
}
```